# Grail : GSP Input parameter name in case of nested list in grails command object

Tags: grails, gsp, command-objects

I am using grails 2.5 , my command object is

```
class TestCommand{
    List aList; // Class A List 
}

class A{
   String name;
   List<B> bList; // Class B List
}

class B{
   String name;
}
```

In my GSP

```
<g:each var="a" in="${aList}" status="i">
    <g:testField name="aList[${i}].name" value="${a?.name}"/>
    <g:each var="b" in="${a.bList}" status="j">
          <g:testField name="aList[${i}].bList[${j}].name" value="${b?.name}"/>
    </g:each>
 </g:each>
```

In my controller I am getting empty list.

Not sure how to rename the input box name so that I can get the concrete list of objects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the code in your controller? Verify in controller that aList have data and is not empty.